# Is it possible to set an encryption password different than lock screen PIN?

Tags: lock-screens, encryption, password

I set up phone encryption using a numeric password. Android 4.4.4 on OnePlus One (Cyanogenmod 11S). Now on the lock screen, I'm asked for the same numeric password (but instead of a text input field, an on-screen numeric pad is shown).

I would like to understand :

- Is it possible to set a different PIN for the lock screen than the one I set before encrypting the phone? (without changing the current encryption password)
- Is it possible to change the encryption password without wiping phone memory?

Answer (score 0):

Please, keep in mind -- one problem, one question here. Two questions in one post is a bad idea.

Now:

- first question: take a look [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/52725/20449) or [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29468) or in many other places,
- second question: **no**, encryption is irreversible!

Once applied the only way to disable it / change password is to do factory reset (loosing all data / wiping phone memory -- as you write) and perform another phone encryption after that.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, in contrast to [trejder's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/169480/44325), the encryption password can certainly be changed without initiating data wiping or factory reset.

Short answer on first question is no, because encryption password will always be changed if lock screen password is changed from UI.